# PythonのzipfileライブラリでUbuntuで作成したパスワード付きzipを解凍したい

Tags: python

```
import zipfile

def unzip(archive, pwtext):
    myzip = zipfile.ZipFile(archive)
    myzip.extractall(path="./output", pwd=pwtext)
    print "Success :)"

def main():
    unfile = "test.zip"
    unpass = b"apple"
    unzip(unfile, unpass)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

上記コードを実行するとパスワードは合っているのにBad password for fileのエラーが出ます。Windowsで作成したzipファイルは正常に解凍できます。Ubuntuにも対応したいため解決策をご教授おねがいします。

実行環境:
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (VirtualBox)
Python 2.7.12
Ubuntu標準の圧縮機能を使用

Comment: unpass(パスワード)への代入でbがダブルクォートの外側にありますが単なる転記ミスでしょうか、もしくは実際のコードも同じですか？

Comment: こちらの環境は Ubuntu 17.10/python 2.7.14/zip 3.0 ですが、展開に成功します(`Success :)` と表示されます)。